# Flutter - Code in StreamBuilder doesn't get executed

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, stream-builder

I am trying to debug the following method, somehow the none of the breakpoints get hit. The one in the catch block also doesn't get hit. I fail to understand what is happening.

```
_getWorkout(workoutId) async {
try {
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("workouts")
          .doc(workoutId)
          .collection("exercises")
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
//doesn't go here---
        print('SNAPSHOT DATA = ' + snapshot.data.toString());
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
//doesn't go here---
          return const Text("There are no exercises");
        }
//doesn't go here---
        return DataTable(  ...

          ],
          rows: _getExercises(snapshot),
        );
      });
} on Exception catch (_, e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(e.toString()),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**StreamBuilder** is a Widget that can convert a stream of user defined objects, to widgets.

You Should include inside Widget build as a widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
     body: Container(
        child:StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("workouts")
                    .doc(workoutId)
                    .collection("exercises")
                    .snapshots(),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    //doesn't go here---
                    print('SNAPSHOT DATA = ' + snapshot.data.toString());
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    //doesn't go here---
                      return const Text("There are no exercises");
                    }
    //doesn't go here---
                    return DataTable();
    
                  }),
    
    ),
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `StreamBuilder` from `_getWorkout`, which you aren't. You are effectively returning null, which will cause flutter to not execute the `StreamBuilder` at all.

Always setting return types on your methods will help in avoiding oversights like that one.